# Override getSchemaFile and getSolrConfigFile

Tags: maven, solr, overriding, solrj, solr4

I'm migrating my Solr test project to Solr 4.1 and I can't override the methods getSchemaFile() and getSolrConfigFile().

I'm getting the following errors:

> [ERROR] my_path/SolrConfigTest.java:[63,15] error: getSchemaFile() in SolrConfigTest cannot override getSchemaFile() in SolrTestCaseJ4
>
> [ERROR] overridden method is static
>
> [ERROR] my_path/SolrConfigTest.java:[62,1] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>
> [ERROR] my_path/SolrConfigTest.java:[68,15] error: getSolrConfigFile() in SolrConfigTest cannot override getSolrConfigFile() in SolrTestCaseJ4
>
> [ERROR] overridden method is static
>
> [ERROR] my_path/SolrConfigTest.java:[67,1] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

The file looks as follows:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.EmbeddedSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.ContentStreamUpdateRequest;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.CoreAdminRequest;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.params.ModifiableSolrParams;
import org.apache.solr.common.util.NamedList;
import org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer;
import org.apache.solr.util.AbstractSolrTestCase;

public class SolrConfigTest extends AbstractSolrTestCase {
    String container = "mycore";

    @Override
    public String getSolrHome() {
        return System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resources/";
    }

    @Override
    public String getSchemaFile() {
        return getSolrHome() + container + "/conf/schema.xml";
    }

    @Override
    public String getSolrConfigFile() {
        return getSolrHome() + container + "/conf/solrconfig.xml";
    }

    @Before
    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        CoreContainer.Initializer initializer = new CoreContainer.Initializer();
        coreContainer = initializer.initialize();
        server = new EmbeddedSolrServer(coreContainer, "mycore");
    }
}
```

And for maven, my pom.xml file has the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
       <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
       <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-test-framework</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Anybody has any idea about what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, AbstractSolrTestCase class at Solr 4.1 does not offer anymore methods getSchemaFile() and getSolrConfigFile() to override.

Once getSolrHome() points to the folder where Solr is defined (where you can find the solr.xml file), the schema.xml and solrconfig.xml files will be found at mycore/conf.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can override initCore(String config, String schema, String solrHome) method of SolrTestCaseJ4 class instead so that you can set the config file and schema file as per your configuration.